# Create identical polygon adjacent to existing

Tags: qgis, polygon, digitizing

I am currently trying to digitize FEMA flood panels and I was wondering if anyone knows how to duplicate existing polygons within QGIS. Specifically I am trying to have identical rectangular polygons adjacent to this one.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Slightly misleading title.

But @ahmadhanb is correct, you can create an identical polygon by copying/pasting. However, what you want is an adjacent polygon of the same dimensions (just not the same locations). In which case, I propose two options:

1 - when editing a feature, the ability to move a feature exists. Create the duplicate and then move it. Snapping also exists, which could be helpful.

2 - you can automatically create a grid, under Vector - Research Tools - Create Grid. Experiment with options here to automatically create a grid of polygons adjacent to each other.

A polygon is made up of points, and each point is defined as a location (with a x/y and sometimes z coordinate). A duplicate polygon would be one in the same location, so what you want is a polygon of the same size and orientation.

Answer (score 2):

An option using the *Geometry by expression* tool:

```sql
collect_geometries(
    $geometry, 
    translate(
        geometry:=$geometry,
        dx:=bounds_width($geometry), 
        dy:=0
    )
)
```

[image]

If you want identical rectangular polygons covering an area, your best bet is probably the *Create grid* tool. `Vector > Research tools > Create grid` (or `Processing toolbox > Vector Creation > Create Grid`). You can set an extent for the grid, and a width and height for the cells.

[image]